# Modelling properties to "relation objects" (like M:N table with additional columns)

Tags: objectbox

I searched everywhere and googled about it, but couldn't find anything about this:
Let's say i have a many to many relationship between 2 table and i want to say that Object A in Object B is of type C. Is it possible here?

Lets say i have a storeBox for Books(virtual books so it can be "many") and a storeBox for Libraries. I can easily do:
Book b = new Book().....
Library.books.put(b)....

But what if i want to save the time this book was added to this library?

Is there a easy way already to do it? or do i need to create a new Entity LibrabyBook with attributes, book_id, library_id and time and when i do a Library.books.put(x) i make a LibraryBook.put(lib, book, time)?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. How would you model it in Java? In ObjectBox, this usually helps because it's object DB which is close to your programming language.

I could image that your suggestion around `LibraryBook` might work using somthing like this:

```
@Entity class Book {
    ...
    List<Library> libraries;
    @Backlink
    List<LibraryBook> bookInLibraries;
}

@Entity class LibraryBook {
    ...
    ToOne<Book> book;
    ToOne<Library> library;
}
```

Comment: Got it, i might do something around this ;)